# KrbException error during token exchange

Tags: java, kerberos, jgss

I'm testing default oracle example
client and server code:

http://pastebin.com/FjGMGwmN 
and got this strange error on linux (in Windows it's another error, i will open another question):

> KrbException: Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate
>   type to decrypt AP REP - AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96

I cant find information how to fix it :(

Comment: Improved formatting, removed tag from title

Answer (score 0):

JCE policy jars was missed
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html
but still:
[java jgss on windows: permanent error: GSSException: Defective token detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37409149/java-jgss-on-windows-permanent-error-gssexception-defective-token-detected)